# Local Variable Unit Testing

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I am coding in C++, and am unit testing a function. This function has a set back though, as I am testing it from an outside source file using GoogleTest. I can't think of way of testing a certain local variable inside it. The function creates a class pointer variable inside itself and deletes it at the end of the function. If I move the local variable declaration into the .h for the overall class, it works just fine and I can do what ever I want to the local variable regardless of it being deleted in the end. So My question is, given that I am not allowed to alter the original setup, is there a way that anyone knows of to access the info from a local variable via some tricky logic or programming voodoo you guys know of? Any advice is appreciated! Also the pointer object in question points to methods in its class and does data manips via input. Ex: pointerA->setWidth(int, int); I need to get to this pointerA in general.

```
foo(int number, int num) {
   classA* pointerA = new classA;  
   pointerA->setWidth(number, num);  
   //other data manipulations  
   delete pointerA;
}
```

Example of Test:

`EXPECT_EQ(pointerA->setWidth(returns width), 2); //checks to see if it returns` correct value of 2

Also the reason I want to be able to do it without having to alter any code is because I'm hoping to let it be automated and run the test every time the code is compiled. It's how I have it set up for all my other tests, but they don't have local vars.

Comment: You should give me an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because I'm confused.

Comment: You probably should test the inner class separately, and then just test the functionality of this function is correct from what you can observe on the outside.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I did that before just to make sure it does work as intended. Via my update to post, want to have it set up for automation so I don't have to go back and retest everytime its been altered.

Comment: The whole point of unit test is that you test a **unit** of the code. You never test local variable. You test the function.

Comment: You should give an MCVE because _you're_ confused.

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to test the value of a local variable. It's local. It has no observable behaviour beyond the innards of the function and are thus part of the unit itself.

Instead you're supposed to test that the function produces the right *outputs* for certain *inputs*. In this case, that's indeed precisely what you're trying to do.<sup>†</sup> The right output is that a `classA` was constructed and its "width" was set correctly by the function under test.

Achieve this by *mocking* `classA`: providing an alternate definition for its member functions, and a way for your testing code to examine its post-test state.

<sub><sup>†</sup> The `classA` is *not* a local variable, so you are asking the wrong question.</sub>